# Eclipse EGit reset HARD. Why it creates new commit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

As I know GIT, **reset** should delete all commits after chosen one. Though this not happen with Eclipse EGit reset (I tried Soft and Hard). Here in reflog I right click and choose reset > hard. What I think should happen - is deletion of all commits after chosen one in reflog.

[image]

But instead I get new commit:

[image]

Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface 4.6.1.201703071140-r org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group Eclipse EGit

Comment: I not sure are you right. Have to get answer first

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate in a sense, that Git Reflog is not a history of commit creation. It is a history of head states which is explained in a linked answer. So what you see is a change of head state, and is an old commit (not newly created). You can confirm this by looking for this commit's hash in older reflog.